# How to protect Hadoop web dashboard with password

Tags: java, hadoop, authentication, jetty, hadoop2

I have configured a small cluster of about 7 system using hadoop 2.7.5. In order to view jobs status I use webapp with port 8088. I want to protect this dashboard with some username/password  so that only auth user can access it. Also there are other port such as 50070 etc., that I want to protect.

Comment: Any attempts so far? Did you setup Kerberos? Have you considered using a reverse proxy?

Comment: I have studied about kerberos but I think it is more than what I need. I just need to protect dashboard and nothing else

Comment: I don't know what "dashboard" you mean. The YARN UI? Yes, you need Kerberos to enable SPNEGO authentication. See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-auth/index.html ... Otherwise, there is no way to pass user credentials to the web ui without otherwise setting up a HTTP Basic Auth server in front of it